# Store Console output per line in an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

As the title says, I'd like to store per line(per `System.out.print`) in an array/arrayList.
So far I have tried `ByteArrayOutputStream` but it only appends everything into one object. I'd be glad to post snippets of the code if necessary. Sorry for the noob problem

Edit Code :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
PrintStream old = System.out;
String[] str= new String[10];

System.setOut(ps);

for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++){
ps.println("Test: "+x);
str[x] = baos.toString();
}
System.out.flush();
System.setOut(old);
for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++){
System.out.println(str[x]);
}
```

Output:

```
Test: 0

Test: 0
Test: 1

Test: 0
Test: 1
Test: 2

Test: 0
Test: 1
Test: 2
Test: 3

Test: 0
Test: 1
Test: 2
Test: 3
Test: 4

Test: 0
Test: 1
Test: 2
Test: 3
Test: 4
Test: 5

Test: 0
Test: 1
Test: 2
Test: 3
Test: 4
Test: 5
Test: 6

Test: 0
Test: 1
Test: 2
Test: 3
Test: 4
Test: 5
Test: 6
Test: 7

Test: 0
Test: 1
Test: 2
Test: 3
Test: 4
Test: 5
Test: 6
Test: 7
Test: 8

Test: 0
Test: 1
Test: 2
Test: 3
Test: 4
Test: 5
Test: 6
Test: 7
Test: 8
Test: 9
```

What I would like to have in `str` array is something like this:

```
str[0] = "Test: 0"
str[1] = "Test: 1"
str[2] = "Test: 2"
str[3] = "Test: 3"
str[4] = "Test: 4"
str[5] = "Test: 5"
str[6] = "Test: 6"
str[7] = "Test: 7"
str[8] = "Test: 8"
str[9] = "Test: 9"
```

I also looked for something like deleting the value inside `ByteArrayOutputStream` but no luck.

Comment: please add the code that you have tried? what is your input? what output you want?

Comment: redirect the output onto a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you post, I made a little modification, see if this is what you are looking for.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
PrintStream old = System.out;
String[] str= new String[10];

System.setOut(ps);

for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++){
ps.println("Test: "+x);
str[x] = baos.toString();
baos.reset();
}
System.out.flush();
System.setOut(old);
for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++){
System.out.println(str[x]);
}
```

The trick is that every time when the line `str[x] = baos.toString()` executed, the accumulated output are still there, so you need use `reset()` to discard the accumulated data, for more details about `reset()`, please refer to the official document [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)